# Will Crystal Reports XI Release 2 work with ASP.NET 4?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-xi

I want to upgrade an old ASP.NET application to ASP.NET 4.0.  It uses several Crystal reports, all which rely on Crystal Reports XI Release 2.  Will they work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes.

install 
http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/us2_default.asp